# Using Raspberry Pi as I/O for webcams

Tags: linux, usb, ffmpeg, webcam, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project where a Raspberry Pi is being used as an I/O board for multiple servos, which are actually controlled by another computer, connected to the RPi via ethernet.

I need to add 2 usb webcams to the project, and would like to connect them to the RPi, to maintain the single location for I/O, if that makes sense.

I'm, looking for the simplest, lowest latency way to forward the input from the webcams to the host machine. I've attempted to use Usbip, and ffmpeg to stream the data, but running into problems with both methods. Are there any other suggestions? or should I keep pursuing one of the methods i've tried.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do your webcams have hardware compression?  Or are you doing compression on the RPi?  Its VideoCore processor is suited for this type of work, but.... you must use OpenMAX to offload to the VideoCore, since the ARM coprocessor where Linux runs is not even close to being able to compress even a low-definition stream.  Programs loading VideoCore codecs are `omxplayer` some `gstreamer` plugins.

Even using the VideoCore, you will have bandwidth problems getting raw video data across the internal interconnect from USB.

Your feasible options are therefore

1. Copy precompressed (inside the webcam itself) video from USB to Ethernet.
2. Use the RPi camera module that interfaces to a high-bandwidth video port on the Raspberry Pi, directly into the VideoCore for processing and compression.

The latter option will likely be quite a bit lower latency, but you get only one stream.  It's theoretically possible to interleave two streams through the single video port, but the codec on the VideoCore would need to be designed to accept and separate the two streams, and the technical data for doing so is available only under NDA to Broadcom's biggest customers.

You can find out more information on the development process for video codecs on the Rasberry Pi forums.  Short version: Broadcom does most of the work, the Raspberry Pi foundation has access to the technical data but not enough engineers, and the NDA forbids them from contracting the work out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually used gstreamer, and got a pretty nice picture on my host machine using this command: `gst-launch -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1" ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=192.168.2.2 port=6789 sync=false` but was about a second behind. I couldn't get it to send over udp, which I figured would be slightly less latency

Comment: @Leon: A second behind what?  The physical action?  The same video appearing on a local display?  Display of the same image with the webcam instead attached to a Windows computer?